# Change property contenteditable in one column with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with columns which properties "contenteditable=false"
If I need to add the property "contenteditable=falsecolumns" to the columns that not have the property "contenteditable=false",
how to do it in Javascript?

**Code that adds the property to all columns**:

**Javascript**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.editbtn').click(function () {
          var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
          alert(currentTD);
          if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {                  
              $.each(currentTD, function () {
                  $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
              });
```

**Table**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="40%">
                Col1
        </th>
        <th width="40%">
                Col2
        </th>
            <th width="20%">
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tr data-id=111>
        <td class='col1' contenteditable="false">A</td>
        <td class='col2'>B</td>
        <td><button class="editbtn">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have a loop, so I will adjust my code to yours. You can place an if statement, like stated below:

```
$.each(currentTD, function () {
   if (!$(this).attr("contenteditable"))
     ;// item doesn't have this attribute
```

Also if you unset the value like this:

```
$(this).prop('contenteditable', "");
```

you can also check whether the value isn't empty

```
  var contenteditable = $(this).attr("contenteditable");
  if (!contenteditable || !contenteditable.length)
     ; // value is empty
```